# How do I remove the invisible border around the page?

Tags: html, css, border, invisible

```
Nothing here
```

Hello. So I have this website https://codepen.io/EleanorFoxQueen/pen/YzOMNQQ and I don't know from when but it now has an invisible border. You can clearly see the purple border is and the website's border creates a gap. Please help me fix it. Thankyou

I don't know what to do

Comment: See [ask] and include a [mcve] please. Also, I'm positive you saw the red warning message stating "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." so why didn't you do as asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

And your `marquee` class has a bottom too. Try removing that

Comment: Please do not answer questions that don't post a [mcve] in them. If codepen ever goes away or is inaccessible, then this question will be useless

Comment: To Amir Safar: It works thankyou so much